# Acquiring domain name but from Japanese registrar

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar

How do I acquire a domain belongs to a Japanese registrar? Registrant detail is under privacy protection service.

Answer (score 1):

All domain owners that use private registration options will be issued a unique email address via some kind of proxy that forwards emails to the domain owner, these will often look something like: `the-domain-name@domainsbyproxy.com`. This information is normally obtainable through any good online whois service.

How you decide to translate your information is your decision and can be done in various ways through online translation services to domain consultancy firms. It's also worth mentioning that the owner may not decide to reply to your emails...he/she or the company may not want to sell the domain.

Other methods could include:

1. Copyright/Trademark Infringement legal proceeding could force the registrar to release the details.
2. Using a whois history service, maybe the owner put privacy settings on after the domain was purchased.
3. Some registrars sell the hidden information (very rare, but does happen).

Answer (score 1):

You obtain it in the usual way - make a deal with the present owner. You can either simply accept the domain's username and password and continue with the present registrar, or follow the applicable domain transfer process. Note that not every registrar will handle `.jp` domains.

If the current owner does not wish to sell (your question is not clear) then you don't get the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this before. My best advice is don't waste your time. You can do 100 whois lookups and chances are you still won't get anywhere. I would not be surprised if it turns out to be not a Japanese registrar at all. Just track the domain over time and maybe you will get lucky.